# Retrofit (1.9.0) what are the failure HTTP,NETWORK,CONVERSION each mean?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

could anybody help, Retrofit onFailure gets getKind error like **HTTP,NETWORK** and **CONVERSION** what these all mean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.9.0/retrofit/RetrofitError.Kind.html

- CONVERSION:
  An exception was thrown while (de)serializing a body.
- HTTP: A non-200 HTTP status code was received from the server.
- NETWORK: An IOException occurred while communicating to the server.
- UNEXPECTED: An internal error occurred while attempting to execute a request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response _/\_ @Alexander Mayatsky :-)